# Adding Library to JRE

Tags: java, security, jar, applet

I work in an enterprise setting where we use a Java applet as part of an internal application. A Java class used by the applet is included in the JDK that we use to develop, but not in the JRE that end users have on their computers. As such, every time the applet is loaded, the users seem to be requesting the class from the server.

Is there a way to "add on" this class to the JRE? Either as a JAR or otherwise?

Comment: how do the user get the jre? is it a through the company?

Comment: Yes, it comes with the default image. We are able to "push" files and programs to users, though. If we just pushed a JAR to the lib/ folder, would it be plausible?

Comment: Okay, do they use Eclipse or some other tool to write code? We use eclipse and in the eclipse initializer, I would just make sure the user has the jar file... If not, place it there.. or something of that nature.

Comment: I'm talking about NON-developers. People without the JDK but with the JRE.

For use within a browser application.

Answer (score 2):

The public API of JDKs from different vendors should be identical. So either you are talking about different versions or you are using "internal API" of the JDK.

The simplest way to ensure compatibility is relying on the "smaller" set as a development environment and adding everything else as external libraries. This way you can just ship what is needed as part of your applet (just repackage everything you need in one fat-jar).

If you are "in control" of your user base: Just ship "your" JDK or ship additional libraries in the ext directory of the JDK/JRE (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ext/basics/install.html) of the user.

You cannot add something to a JRE from an applet, this defeats the idea of an applet running in a sandbox.

Comment: I think you've got it with the ext. Thank you!

To be specific, we weren't going to use the applet to write to the JRE folders. We wanted to add a file to the JRE somewhere so that it doesn't have to load every time the cache expires. It's a Data-conversion thing, not specific to the applet.

Comment: Be carefull however when putting stuff in ext. 
You might risk classloader problems if someone else is using the same library, but having it integrated in a different version.

Comment: I'd still say: (re-)packaging it as part of the applet is probably the safest choice.

Answer (score 2):

You can put the classes packed in a JAR file on $JRE/lib/ext. The classes will be acessible to any Java App where uses that JRE.

Read it, for more details: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ext/basics/install.html

Answer (score 2):

> As such, every time the applet is loaded, the users seem to be requesting the class from the server.

Appearances can be deceptive.  The JRE will report downloading from the server even if the file is locally cached.  This is for security reasons.