# ClassNotFoundException when I am trying to connect to PostgreSQL with JDBC

Tags: java, database, eclipse, postgresql, jdbc

I have a problem trying to connect to PostgreSQL 11 using Java 10.0.2. I am using an Eclipse 2018-09 IDE. 
So first, I downloaded the driver postgresql-42.2.5 and I located it in the folder lib of my jdk-11. Then I tried to execute the following code:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class Connect {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
            System.out.println("Driver O.K.");

            String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/Ecole";
            String user = "postgres";
            String passwd = "postgres";

            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, passwd);
            System.out.println("Connection succeded !");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

That doesn't seem to work because I got a `ClassNotFoundException`:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at Connect.main(Connect.java:8)
```

As an other attempt (which I don't know if it could help) I tried to add a user Library from the IDE and add the path of the Driver manually (eventually it did not help), and as a result I got the exact same error as above.

I could use any help as a beginner in java, thank you!

Comment: Sure this is the output:

 Driver O.K.

java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/Ecole
 at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
 at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
 at Connect.main(Connect.java:15)

Comment: right click on project, go to buildpath--> add external libraries --> add postgres jar

Comment: @Deadpool Great answer, that works!

Comment: You cannot put random libraries in the `lib` folder of your Java installation: that doesn't work. You need to add it to the classpath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `PostgreSQL-JDBC-Driver-jar` to the `Libraries` in Project->Build Path

**Right click on Project--> Build Path--> Configure Build Path-->Libraries TAP--> Add External Jars

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can add Additional libraries (JAR) in the $JRE/lib/ext Folder

[Adding Library to JRE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29850917/adding-library-to-jre)

Comment: You should not put things in `lib/ext` (and in recent Java versions (Java 9 and higher), that option doesn't even exist anymore).